# Ember.computed not functioning as expected when defined within a method

Tags: ember.js

I am attempting to use Ember.computed to setup a computed property from within one of my view's methods.  I tried to use the syntax shown in this fiddle, but as you can see, it does not seem to actually do what I was hoping.  Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/skane/H5ma5/1/

```
this.set('myComputed', Ember.computed(function() {return "funky"}).property());
```

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work this way, since Ember has to do perform some of its magic. I had a look at the source of Ember and found [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/properties.js#L78):

```
// define a computed property
  Ember.defineProperty(contact, 'fullName', Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
  }).property('firstName', 'lastName'));

  @method defineProperty
  @for Ember
  @param {Object} obj the object to define this property on. This may be a prototype.
  @param {String} keyName the name of the property
  @param {Ember.Descriptor} [desc] an instance of `Ember.Descriptor` (typically a
    computed property) or an ES5 descriptor.
    You must provide this or `data` but not both.
  @param {anything} [data] something other than a descriptor, that will
    become the explicit value of this property.
```

So the following should work in your case:

```
Ember.defineProperty(this, 'myComputed', Ember.computed(function() {
    return "funky";
}).property());
```

Comment: excellent digging.  This is also the answer I eventually settled on.  kudos.

Comment: How do you then provide that computed property with a dependent key so that it stays updated?